# Jquery: clear content added with :before in css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu, where 
    `ul li a:before{content: "sth";}`
How with jquery on click change this content and then after second click put it back and so on?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content),

The content property can also show a attribute value of that element.

Example:

```
content: attr('data-value');
```

So, in your case, use jquery to change the attribute value instead of trying to change the `content` css property value. If you just change/toggle the attribute value, indirectly, the `content` css property value will change.

Example:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var data = self.data('value');
    self.data('value', (data == "sth" ? data : "something else here"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is to create relevant class.

i.e.

CSS:

```
.content:before{
    content:"sth";
}
```

JS:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("content");
});
```

[See DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/sp99tnu9/)